# Exit a loop from terminal

Tags: python, object

I would like to know how to leave a loop from the terminal, otherwise when closing it...[image]

Thanks!

I tried 'exit', 'leave' and others keywords like that

Comment: ctrl + c kills most things in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mac and Windows: `control + C`. In general it terminate a process.

Answer (score 0):

try adding keyboard Interrupt exception

```py
try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
    print "Stopped"
    raise
```